# Composer uses wrong php version, but php -v shows the correct one (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php

I'm trying to install my composer packages, but it gives me this:

`This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.5.9)`

But `php -v` gives me this: `PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )`

I am running an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS machine, I found some soultions for Mac and Windows, but nobody seems to have the issue on Linux?

Comment: what does a phpinfo(); call show in your browser?  did you previously have 5.5.9 installed before installing 7.x?

Comment: Be careful, because CLI version can be different that phpinfo() shows.

Comment: you need to use alias php command  just to pass the session

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try this:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

or this in composer.json

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0.0"
    }
}
```

in the second solution basically you're faking a platform, and run `composer.phar update` after this

Comment: this works, but what is the cause for this? `which php` shows `/usr/bin/php` and `/usr/bin/php -v` shows `7.0.22` as well...

Comment: @PrimuS, I don't know, may be a `composer`'s bug. It always had problems with PHP versions. So just make it accept it. It's Ok

Comment: @PrimuS, provided that you're not using two platforms such as (Xampp and Wamp ) at the same time?

Comment: This is the actual solution.. Thanks for the answer

Comment: No, ignoring platform requirements is plain wrong and it hides the actual problem itself. Make sure, you have only one PHP version installed. Then this should fix the issue. See my reply below.

Comment: @Roland is correct this is not an answer by any means. & @Roland is slightly wrong, OP can have multiple PHP versions but have set desired one as default. In ubuntu OP can use  `sudo apt update-alternative --config php` for that

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things - hackjobs...

Comment: Downvoted with a vengeance for offering a hack around the problem instead of a solution to the underlying issue.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Debian based systems, you can ask it to globally use a specific version with the following command (depending on how and where your php versions are installed to):

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

> update-alternatives creates, removes, maintains and displays
>   informations about the symbolic links comprising the Debian
>   alternatives system.

Answer (score 4):

Try this it worked for me :

```
  alias php='/usr/local/php7/bin/php'

php composer.phar install
```

Comment: Found out I had hardcoded php version `alias m='/usr/bin/php7.4 -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento'` that was the reason `$ m s:d:c` was failing with error *Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.4.33*

Answer (score 4):

`composer`references the PHP executable here as follow:

`#!/usr/bin/env php`

When I do `which php` I get `/c/Program Files/php-7.1/php` under GIT-Bash (Windows 10).

Under Linux (at home I have Debian), `php` may be a symbolic link to an actual PHP binary.

So do the following:

- Double-check the said `php` with `` ls -l `which php` ``
- Make sure that you only have one PHP version installed, this may cause mixing incompatible versions which may be the root cause of your problem

That should help you, finding the root cause.

Comment: Do you know how to redirect composer to reach to this file/version of PHP? Im also having issues where by showing phpinfo() im getting 7.4 but Composer is using 7.3, this file has 7.4 in it and I would like to use that. Thanks!

Comment: While I would love to just run 1 php version, I am on a shared host.  Any way to make this work properly on shared hosting.  It is detecting the host's default of 7.2 instad of my default of 7.4

Comment: @Eduardo and @Kevin-Finkenbinder I think your both solution is to download `composer.phar` yourself and execute it with proper `php-7.4` version: https://getcomposer.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across the same problem. `php --version` returned `7.4.30`, but Composer said it was using PHP 8.0.18.

It turns out Composer is using its own PHP version. The `composer` script contains a hardcoded path to PHP 8. (To me, this is a composer bug, as Composer should respect the value of the `config.platform.php` property of the `composer.json` file.)

1. An option may be to *alias* `composer`:

   ```bash
   alias composer='/usr/local/bin/php /usr/bin/composer.phar
   ```
2. Another option may be to rewrite `composer`:

   ```bash
   cat /usr/bin/composer \
       | sed 's~/usr/bin/php8~/usr/local/bin/php~g' \
       > /usr/bin/composer.tmp
   mv /usr/bin/composer.tmp /usr/bin/composer
   ```

---

This is how I found out. First, I wanted to find the location of `composer`. By using `whereis composer`, one can find the path of the `composer` command. For me, it returned

```
composer: /usr/bin/composer
```

I then wanted to see the contents of `/usr/bin/composer`, so I could find out what the `composer` command was doing under the hood. By using `cat /usr/bin/composer`, the contents of the `composer` script are printed. For me, it returned

```bash
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/php8 /usr/bin/composer.phar "$@"
```

There it is. The `composer` command uses hardcoded `/usr/bin/php8` to execute the `composer.phar` file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this worked for me

```
$ alias composer="php /usr/bin/composer.phar"
$ composer install
```

Use the exact php binary in the alias, for example

```
$ alias composer="php8.1 /usr/bin/composer.phar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing here because I had this same issue and found this thread first while searching.
For me I had a Windows server with PHP 5.6.? on it as well as PHP 7.2.? on it. I had configured IIS to use 7.2 but 5.6 was still in the environment variables under path. Open System Properties>Advanced tab> "Environment Variables...". Edit "path", and remove the reference to "C:/program files (x86)/PHP/v5.6" from path and save.
Restart your terminal and you should be set. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

None of above didnt worked for centos 7.
After this command composer php version fixed
The correct answer below

SSH Command:

```
scl enable ea-php74 'composer diagnose'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php81/root/usr/bin/php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer install
```

Above command solved my issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34931560)