# Composer memory limit using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I am getting the error below when I ran `docker-compose run --rm composer install`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 84

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 84

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.ERROR: 255
```

I have added the `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` in my `docker-compose.yml` file. Below is the snippet of the yml file.

```
composer:
    image: graze/composer:php-7.0
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['composer']
    environment:
        - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
    command: install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: I had this myself when I used the smallest DigitalOcean-Droplet. The host just had not enough memory allocated. Solution was to go to a bigger Droplet

Comment: Have you checked whether your system has more memory? Which version of PHP and Composer are you using?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am using PHP 7.0 (needed for legacy application as per requirement) while composer is version 1.5.1 as used by the docker image.

Comment: @BertC using this in my local environment, not on digital ocean. I have computer has 32GB of memory and I think docker is limiting per container.

Comment: Compser in v1.5.1? That's nearly four years old, and I would assume that a lot of things happened in the meantime to boost the performance. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914104/composer-uses-wrong-php-version-but-php-v-shows-the-correct-one-ubuntu to get hints about how to run the latest versions of PHP and Composer, but still install packages for PHP 7.0

Answer (score 0):

You should edit `composer.json` to contain a constraint for the PHP version you are using. This could look like:

```
"require": {
    "php": "7.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0.0"
    }
}
```

Now all usages of `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` would honor this, and no incompatible packages should get installed.

This means: you're free to use whatever version of PHP or Composer to update and install your dependencies, independent from the PHP version used to run your application afterwards. Composer is instructed to act like you've called it with the version configured in `config.platform.php`

Comment: Using lumen 5.3 on a separate image and container. Will this not be affected? PHP version should still be as is as we cannot afford to do regression testing on our app should we upgrade the PHP version as the application is huge.

Comment: Also, I already have "install --ignore-platform-reqs" on my docker-compose.yml file under "command"

Comment: Now this is weird.. On my bash, upon running `docker-compose run --rm composer install` it gave me a bunch of error similar to this `algolia/algoliasearch-client-php 1.28.1 requires php ^5.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.` However, upon checking my docker CLI logs, it is installing all dependencies. How come?

Comment: "separate image and container" - these should not be affected. Also, I forgot to add `--ignore-platform-reqs` to the command, sorry